# Ternary operator to evaluate to true if string or false if bool

Tags: php

```
function file_get_contents_new($url, $wait = 3) {
    if (http_response($url, '200', $wait)) {
        return file_get_contents($url);
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
function OO_chart($query_stub, $length)
    {
        $key = $this->OO_charts_key;
        $url_api = "https://api.oocharts.com/v1/query.jsonp?query={$query_stub}&key={$key}&start={$length}";
        $json = file_get_contents_new($url_api);
        if (file_get_contents_new($url_api) ? (string) true : (bool) false && (bool) $this->OO_active) {
            return json_decode($json, TRUE);
        } else {
            $msg = new Messages();
            $msg->add('e', 'JSON error. Check OOcharts api.');
            redirect('index.php');
        }
    }
```

Will file_get_contents_new($url_api) ? (string) true : (bool) false work in this way?
As in, will it evaluate to `true` if the function outputs a `string`,
and will it evaluate to `false` if the function is `bool`?

Comment: Have you tried it yet?

Comment: See my answer, I suggested the use of alternative type-evaluations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_get_contents_new()` returns the read data or FALSE on failure.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

So why complicate things? This should work. But there is only one way to find out...

```
    $contents = file_get_contents_new($url_api);

    if (($contents!==false) && (bool) $this->OO_active) {
         return json_decode($json, TRUE);
    }
```

Also I don't like the `(bool`) assignment. Isn't that parameter supposed to be `boolean` already?

And to answer your question - YES a ternary operator inside an if statement should work. But it's just hard to test, debug, maintain, and makes your code less readable. I don't like to use it like this.

Answer (score 2):

**No**. Your trying to type-juggle (switching the data type of a variable) in the `if(){}else{}` statement.

The correct way to do this is to change your if statement to the following:

```
if (is_string(file_get_contents_new($url_api)) && is_bool($this->OO_active)) {
   return json_decode($json, TRUE);
} else {
   $msg = new Messages();
   $msg->add('e', 'JSON error. Check OOcharts api.');
   redirect('index.php');
}
```

Now, as you saw, I made use of the `is_bool()` and `is_string()` functions in PHP. If your function `file_get_contents_new` returns a string, it will evaluate to true, and check if `$this->OO_active` is a boolean or not. If your `file_get_contents_new` function returns a boolean (meaning it is NOT a string), it will immediately perform your `else{}` statement, because both of your `if` conditions must be true (because of the `&&`/`and` operators), and if one of those conditions returns false, or breaks the chain, it will move to the `else` statement.

Answer (score 1):

No, that wont work. Translated back to a normal if/else it's easier to explain why this wont work:

```
if( !file_get_contents($file) ){
    // the file_get_contents function returned false, so something went wrong
}
else{
    // the if-condition was not met, so the else will do its job
    // The problem is that we got the content in the if-condition, and not in a variable
    // therefor we can not do anything with its contents this way
    echo "It did work, but I have no way of knowing the contents";
}
```

A solution could be like this:

```
$content = file_get_contents($file);
$content = $content===false ? 'No content' : $content; // rewrite if file_get_contents returns false
```

Be a little carefull with the ternary check, use triple equal signs. In some bizar situation the content of the file could be 'false'. Checking if `$content==false` would return true because it has the same value (but not the same type (string/boolean)

Comment: `$contents = file_get_contents($file); if($contents !== FALSE) { // Do stuff } else { "It did not work!"; }` ???

Comment: I was giving simplefied code to explain the train of thought, you need to custumize it a bit

Comment: `it did work but I have no way of knowing the contents` === FALSE

Comment: No, the file_get_contents worked fine, that is the problem with using ternary this way. The file_get_contents did get the contents, it just hasn't been saved in any variable. The else means it did work, but because the content is never saved, there is no way of using it.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest using `No, that wont work. Your code to a normal if/else would equal this:`